# How do I make all drives visible in Nautilus over ssh?

Tags: mount, ssh, nautilus, disk

Currently if I connect to my remote machine over ssh and run nautilus (ignoring occasional crashes and all the funny stuff that desktop does) I can't see all mountable disks/volumes. I can mount them manually using mount but I would like to have exactly the same access to the drives as I would have directly on that machine. How do I do that?